# Xcode bots error - Could not write data. Invalid Argument (-1)

Tags: xcode, osx-server, xcode-bots

Receiving these errors every time I do an Integration on  Xcode bots. Using 6.4 version of Xcode on one machine connecting to 4.1.3 version of OS X Server on the server. I have 12 bitbucket git repos and 10 of them are working okay (meaning they are being checked out properly by the Bot); only 2 are giving errors. I have no clue how and where to look to resolve this.

*Bot Issue: error. Build Service Error.
Issue: 2 errors occured:
 • DVTSourceControlRemoteRepository:git@bitbucket.org:teamABC/repoXXX.git System:Git (com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcec.
Integration Number: 3
Integration URL: 
Description: 2 errors occured:
 • DVTSourceControlRemoteRepository:git@bitbucket.org:teamABC/repoXXX.git System:Git (com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcecontrol.Git 0.21.0) Authentication:SSH Key Authentication (file:///Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Caches/8e806b24d9f709bee83cc5e00b0170b3/SSHKeys/14B4E66A-1834-4AD1-BA05-BB15A0A14E1F/id_rsa) -> Failed to mmap. Could not write data: Invalid argument (-1)
 • DVTSourceControlRemoteRepository:git@bitbucket.org:teamABC/repoYYY.git System:Git (com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcecontrol.Git 0.21.0) Authentication:SSH Key Authentication (file:///Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Caches/8e806b24d9f709bee83cc5e00b0170b3/SSHKeys/BB570BB6-D8B8-4DF6-A6BB-1980190D40E7/id_rsa) -> Failed to mmap. Could not write data: Invalid argument (-1)*

I have tried doing the below but no luck:

```
sudo xcrun xcscontrol --reset
sudo xcrun xcscontrol --initialize
```

I have also tried using http instead of ssh for two problematic repos but no luck (again)

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the output you copied there it looks like it's an ssh issue.  Did you add the ssh key to your repo that Xcode generates when you built the bot?

Comment: Yes. Added that key as the team account ssh key on bitbucket. 10 repos are cloning fine onto the xcode server machine. There is something peculiar going on with the other 2 repos which I am not able to figure out.

Comment: I know that on my projects, i have an ssh key per project, so I add a new one each time, otherwise it won't let me past the credentials part of building the bot

Comment: Tried adding ssh key per project but no luck. Still same errors.

Comment: if you go to the build log how far does it get? or does it even get that far?

Comment: It's not even reaching the build stage. It is failing at the checkout part during bot integration. The error above is what I see in the "summary" section of the bot integration and also in xcsbuildd.log on the os x server. There is nothing in the "Logs" section of the bot integration.

Comment: if its not getting that far then it definitely sounds like a git access issue.  Check all of your settings, make sure the bot has access to the repo. Try making it public project as a test to see if anything changes, or make a new test repo that is public, and put an empty project in there that will compile and make a new bot.  Go through the steps of setting it up, use create new ssh key and add it to the repo.

Comment: I was able to get past this issue just by upgrading to xcode 7 and os x server 5. Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: no problem sorry I couldn't help you but glad you figured it out

Comment: You also need to run `--preflight`. Or just use https://github.com/czechboy0/xcskarel